# Deleted Shell on WSL and Cannot Access WSL

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

During an attempt to remove zsh from Ubuntu running on WSL, I ran:

sudo apt-get --purge remove zsh

Foolishly, I did not reset my default shell, so I cannot access WSL. The windows flashes open and then closes.

I can see from powershell that all of my files in WSL are still available, but I do not know how to reset the default shell in WSL from Powershell.

How can I reinstall bash or zsh from Powershell?

Answer (score 3):

So I figured this out. From an 'elevated' powershell I executed the following commands:

cd \wsl$<distro name>
wsl -e bash
sudo vipw

From there, I went to /etc/passwd and changed the shell on my username to bash.

Comment: chsh would have been an alternative to vipw

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

First launch wsl with bash shell

```
wsl -e bash
```

Then either re-install the missing shell, or revert your default shell back to bash with :

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

*Worked for me on Debian in WSL2 where I uninstalled fish shell.*